# Connect to a newly installed SQL Server from another computer

Tags: sql-server

I have one windows server 2016 named X. Here, SQL Server is installed by another person Y but management studio is not installed. I want to connect to X from my own computer using management studio. I have the server IP but what should I write to user name and password, are there any default values for them?

Also, in that X server SQL Server, configuration manager is missing. I can only see it under computer management-services and applications.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go by parts you can use the windows authentication option to try to connect (it will work if the user is created) if not, it will be necessary to create.
In server name you can put the name of the X machine or the IP.
About the configuration manager you can use the shortcut as described in the link

[Configuration Manager](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sql-server-configuration-manager/#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20Server%20configuration%20manager,msc%E2%80%9D%20file.)